# Does namespace break ABI?

Tags: c++, dll, abi

I have searched some articles about C++ (COM-like) ABI Interface of DLL,
for example: ["Exporting C++ classes from a DLL"](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll/) and ["Binary-compatible C++ Interfaces"](http://chadaustin.me/cppinterface.html), they're very nice and helpful, but they didn't talk about namespace.

Does namespace break ABI ?

```
namespace Foo {

    class Listener {
        virtual void e1() = 0;
        virtual void e2() = 0;
    };

    class Interface {
        virtual void setListener(Listener*) = 0;
        virtual int f1() = 0;
        virtual int f2() = 0;
    };

}

extern "C" Foo::Interface* SOME_API createFooInterface();
```

I have no idea, does it work ?

---

Sorry, I'm just not being clear, my English writing ability is not very well.

In my code snippet, extern "C" is preventing name mangling in C++ DLL exports, name mangling is **incompatible** between C++ compilers, the two articles mentioned above are talking about this question.

My meaning about "break ABI" is:
I can do this in MSVC, I can use namespace for my C++ interface classes, I can export a DLL from this code, but I am not sure this interface is still ABI - A Binary-compatible interface between compilers, it's not about two namespaces, it's about two or more compilers.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try, and tell us?

Comment: @DevSolar Because of complexity. I can't try each complier and a try will not be enough. I don't know is there some de facto standard about this.

Comment: Well, if your example actually *allowed* that test, I could tell you the results of half a dozen compilers, which should be a good *start* even if it isn't chapter and verse of the standard. Since it doesn't, take this as a subtle hint that your question leaves something to be desired, i.e. research effort. Or, to put it differently: How, in your mind, should `Foo::Interface *` be flattened to "C" linkage, i.e. without name mangling, and still be distinguishable from e.g. `Bar::Interface *`? How could the **C** function `createFooInterface()` return a **C++** construct (a namespaced type)?

Comment: @amanjiang: Tests are effective in proving that something does **not** work, they just can't help you prove that something will **always** work. In this case, DevSolar has a point: A C++ namespace change will affect the C++ ABI. I don't see why you are writing `extern "C"` when discussing C++ ABI's, though. That defeats the point.

Comment: Namespaces are a compiler concept and disappear after compilation.  Talking about ABI is just not appropriate, C++ rules apply here.  Virtual dispatch tables can be emulated in C, there's just nothing much fun about it.  Tooling helps, like MIDL in the COM world which can auto-generate the C declarations from the IDL.

Comment: @MSalters Because of binary compatible, name mangling is incompatible, it's DLL exporting. I think "extern C" is a pure C++ grammar, it's just about linkage. A extern "C" function could return a namespaced interface in msvc, and you can put it into namespace too. But my question was, I am not sure it will works well in all COM-compatible compliers.

Comment: If you'll change namespace, function will still return a pointer. How you use this pointer is a bit different story. You probably need to clarify what you want to achieve with this thing and how it is being used. Sharing C++ objects this way between different compilers isn't safe either.

Comment: @keltar I won't change namespace. I will export a DLL from one compiler(msvc), and other people will use this DLL in some different compilers with the header file(so namespace is just the same). If there is no namespace, this way will be good, it's an Idiom. The question is what's going on if I introduce namespace.

Comment: @amanjiang if you think that using it without namespace is okay, then namespace adds no difference, if all functions are pure virtual. However, compilers aren't obligated to handle class fields or virtual table accesses in the same way. (not related to namespace - it could fail anyway).

Comment: @keltar On Windows, compiler vendors enforced the mapping between COM vtables and C++ vtables, it's not a problem. But function overriding may break this rule, so we will not use overriding. Please take a look at the articles mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

It has to. Since two functions can be identical apart from their namespace, the ABI must be able to distinguish the two. I.e. they must have unique names. Thus, changing the namespace deletes one function and introduces another, with the compiler having no idea of the relation between the two. Compilers don't read your Git or SVN comments.